# how to convert a JSON string into an array using JSON.simple in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have an string representation of an array of objects. How do I use JSON.simple to take that string and create a Java array of objects? The sting looks something like the following:

```
 String info = [
    {
        "name": "name",
        "title": "Name",
        "type": "String",
        "maxLength": 100,
        "minLength": 0,
        "required": true
    },
    {
        "name": "eMail",
        "title": "E-mail",
        "type": "String",
        "maxLength": 100,
        "minLength": 0,
        "required": false
    }
```

]

Im not allowed to use GSON unfortunately, which would make this solution easier.

Comment: Can you provide your code?  If you have not started coding I suggest you find a tutorial to follow such as the following: https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: This is mid project. I have the json string stored in the database, I need to pull that string and parse it into a java object. In order to validate the length and other requirements before storing user input into the database. I must use JSON.simple, no Jackson or GSON. I have every other piece, just cant change the stringified array into a java array.

Comment: You still need to provide enough code to replicate your problem so it can modified appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your String variable needs to escape double quotes, like this:

```
    String info = "[ {\"name\": \"name\",\"title\": \"Name\",\"type\": 
    \"String\",\"maxLength\": 100,\"minLength\": 0,\"required\": true }, 
    {\"name\":: \"eMail\",\"title\": \"E-mail\",\"type\": \"String\",\"maxLength\": 
    100,\"minLength\": 0,\"required\": false}]";
```

You can parse the string and covert the result into JSONArray type, then iterate through the JSONArray and save the data into a Java array.

```
    Object obj = parser.parse(info);
    JSONArray infoJsonArray = (JSONArray) obj;

    // save to a java array
    List<JSONObject> objAry = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator iter = infoJsonArray.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        JSONObject o = (JSONObject) iter.next();
        objAry.add(o);
    }

    System.out.println(objAry.get(0).toString()); // {"minLength":0,"name":"name","title":"Name","type":"String","maxLength":100,"required":true}
    System.out.println(objAry.get(1).get("name")); // eMail
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make if as Java Object, I'd suggest to go with Jackson ObjectMapper.

```
    String jsonCarArray =
        "[{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }, { \"color\" : \"Red\", \"type\" : \"FIAT\" }]";
    List<Car> listCar = objectMapper.readValue(jsonCarArray, new TypeReference<List<Car>>(){});
```

Refer to this [Link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)
 might help you out.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use JSON.simple or org.json.JSONArray library. Otherwise I would have used GSON which can solve this issue with a couple lines of code